# How to Start with learning Hindu Sastra and Vedas?

Tags: vedas, belief

I am a 28 years, Madhwa Brahmin working as Software Engineer. I was an atheist during most part of my life. But recently I have got strong interest and belief in learning Hindu Sastra and Vedas. Could you please kindly share your suggestions on how to begin with and also how to pursue learning Vedas professionally.

Thanks

Comment: ask your parents, grandparents, their gurus, your local temple priest.. if all that fails, then ask internet :)

Comment: @ram - Thanks for your suggestion. I currently live in abroad and have no good access to those things mentioned by you.  Since I have been following this site, I have posted this question here..

Comment: Just use the internet. There are loads of information on it. You do not need a guru. Btw are you religious now or still an atheist?

Comment: @Wikash - I am not an atheist as I have belief in the religion and God. I have had personal experiences which is encouraging me more to learn and gain spiritual knowledge.

Comment: What convinced you if may ask? If you want to discuss this on another platform I am also open to that.